# Variable substitution with conditions

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to do variable substitution depending on some conditions.

I have two variables,
`act_nic` and `con_name`.

The `act_nic` variable always has some value (not empty)
but the value of `con_name` may be null or sometimes it may have a value.

I have multiple commands like below,

```
nmcli connection modify ${act_nic} ipv6.never-default yes
```

In the place of `act_nic`, if `con_name` is not null then it should take the `con_name` value in the place of `act_nic`.

I have tried

```
${con_name:-act_nic}
```

The above will produce `act_nic` as a plain string, but it's not taking the actual value of the variable `act_nic`.

I have other ways where I can check if con_name is not null then set `act_nic=$con_name`, but I do not want to do this in that way as the value of act_nic is used elsewhere in the script, too.

I am trying to do this in single line. I'm using RHEL if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you discovered, the string after `:-` is just static. To put a variable's expansion there, use the regular variable expansion syntax.

```
${con_name:-$act_nic}
```

As a general guideline, probably add quoting if the values are not guaranteed to only consist of characters which have no special meaning to the shell; see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Maybe even `${con_name:-${act_nic}}` to point out the recursiveness ;-)